# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value and sequence does not exit

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm using oracle sql developer and create a table named `avatar`. It has two columns , `avatarid` and `image` .

I also create a trigger and sequence for id auto generation .
But when I use this table with hibernate and spring tool suite , I got an exception ,that is

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next
>   sequence value.

It says

> sequence does not exit

I try all the answers but can't fix the error. In Sprig Tool Suite , I connect to database using datasource and search my sequence under my schema , and my sequence doesn't exit. 
I created the sequence along with trigger using Oracle SQL Developer.

Please give me some more advice.

Here is my Avatar.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.bluestone.fileupload.model.Avatar" table="avatar">
<id name="avatarid" type="int">
<column name="AVATARID" />
<generator class="sequence">
<param name="my_seq">SU_AVATAR_SEQUENCE</param>
</generator>
</id>
<property name="image" type="binary">
<column name="IMAGE" not-null="true" />
</property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And , this is my Avatar.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avatar")
public class Avatar{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  generator = "my_seq")
private int avatarid;
private byte[] image;

public Avatar() {

}

public Avatar(int avatarid, byte[] image) {
super();
this.avatarid = avatarid;
this.image = image;
}

public void setAvatarid(int avatarid) {
this.avatarid = avatarid;
}
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh for good edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure is the sequence is available in the database
2) May be you need to use schema say eg : HR.SU_AVATAR_SEQUENCE
where HR is the schema name 
3)Else create sysnonym for schema

Comment: My sequence doesn't exit under my schema when I search using datasource in Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: i think u need to create synonym or you can mention synonym in the hbm file itself

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_seq_gen_9")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq_gen_9", sequenceName = "SEQ_NAME_YOUR")
    @Column(name = "COLUMN")
    private long columnName;
```

Sequence can used as in hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

My Resolution was:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ACTIVITY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
```